# How to write the degree (grade) symbol in Firefox with a US english layout?

Tags: firefox, unicode

I'm trying to write the degree/grade (°) symbol in Firefox so I can write °C, for example, but each time I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0176</kbd> doesn't work since Firefox has <kbd>Alt</kbd> + any number as keybindings for changing tabs, so another method is desirable. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm currently on Firefox 24, and it lets me write ° symbol with Alt+0176 (as you see, I have typed it)... So, I'm not sure, but maybe update will help you?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela super user is for anyone, using any OS, be it Linux or Windows. It has everything to do with Firefox, as I'm trying to use firefox to do this.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I'd refresh your knowledge on the [about] page, about what's on topic or not

Comment: Whatever Superuser is for, the *question* was grossly misleading (it did not mention Linux at all), and it still is, since Firefox is not the issue here. The issue is system-dependent input methods, but the question (and the poster’s own answer) seriously obscures this. If you want to ask how to do something in Linux, be my guest, but please don’t present it as a Firefox problem, and please make it clear from the start what you are asking about.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I edited the answer before your comment to add that in *Linux* you can use Unicode. Your principal problem was with "heavily system dependent" methods, which it was the specific reason why I didn't tell what OS I was using so anyone (be it windows, *NIX, OSX) could answer the question. This is done on proupose so many answers could be given for any OS. Your first comment in my answer states so, for that reason I had to downvote yours since as same as mine isn't platform independient. There are no wrong answers, just different aproaches depending the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this in any major platform:

1. Open your system character palette:

   - Windows: **Start > Accessories > System Tools > Character Map** or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `charmap`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - OS X: <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or **Edit > Special Characters...**
   - Linux:

     - Gnome: Launch `gucharmap`
     - KDE: Launch `kcharselect`
2. Find the desired symbol
3. Copy and Paste into application at desired location.

Other, less tedious methods include:

- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> on OS X
- <kbd>Compose</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>O</kbd> on systems with Compose-key support (Linux, Windows with a custom keyboard)

Answer (score 3):

If <kbd>Alt</kbd> *number* has been taken (naughty!), then you can try the <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> *code* method (where *code* is the Unicode number in hex), i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>. But quite often it does not work; it would then require a [change to Windows registry](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm). Then I guess you would need to install a separate program for typing characters, or maybe a suitable keyboard layout.

Comment: Alt + B calls the bookmarks, so it doesn't work and it isn't platform independient.

Comment: The Windows registry doesn't solve an issue in Linux

Comment: This answer was based on the *original* question, which did not mention Linux at all and strongly implied Windows. (Why would anyone even try Alt 0176 on other systems?)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - You should provide what registry changes are require, to make this solution work, since incomplete without those directions.

Comment: Added link for the info. This question should be closed, however. The formulation of the question, including its title, is grossly misleading. The topic is important, and therefore it would deserve a well-formulated question, with answers that address the same question.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, in Linux you can type it in Unicode format:

- In Unicode it is encoded at U+00B0 ° degree sign, so press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, then type `00B0` and press enter or space, then you get the symbol.
- If what you want is the celsius degrees symbol (℃) you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, then type `2103` same as above.

For now the best to use is the degree symbol alone so it allows you to use `F`, `K` or for angular degrees, etc.

Comment: Things like Ctrl Shift U are heavily system-dependent and probably don’t do anything useful in Windows, which is where Alt 0176 works. The character U+2103 is *not* recommended in Unicode. The degree sign “°” has *not* been part of the correct symbol for the kelvin (K) for decades.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela But it doesn't work in firefox, in any OS I've tried, if you could try I invite you to do so. Also, as you **can read in my question** Alt + 0176 **do NOT work** and this method solves my question.

Comment: Since Alt 0176 is specifically a Windows method, it was grossly misleading to ask about it without telling that you are working with Linux. There was no reason to even try Alt 0176 then. Besides, in different Linux distributions, different methods need to be used.